# mysqli not supported in google app engine with php

Tags: php, mysql, google-app-engine, mysqli

I am trying to set my script on google app engine, and I have problem with mysqli support for php. When I run it, I get message

> Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in

I tried `phpinfo()` but there is no mysqli extenstion there

Then I tried configuring php.ini like here https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/config/php_ini

and I added

```
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=mysqli.so
extension=mysql.so
```

and uploaded it in base directory as explaned but still no success, how can I fix it. I can see PDO, but I would need to change everything in script and it takes too much time.

app.yaml is listed below

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1

env_variables:
  # Replace project, instance, database, user and password with the values obtained
  # when configuring your Cloud SQL instance.
  MYSQL_DSN: mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/datahouse;dbname=db
  MYSQL_USER: root
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'pass'

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: test.php
```

I am running the app with this

```
dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=/usr/bin/php-cgi $PWD
```

Comment: Once you added the mysqli extension did you restart the webserver?

Comment: it should not work like that in google app engine, each time I run the app it is reloaded

Comment: i got same problem too...any update ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `php.ini` to your project root (the same level with `app.yaml`):

```
extension = "mysqli.so"
```

Comment: I did it with or without quotation marks and nothing happens. No change, and it is in same directory as app.yaml

Comment: Can I see your app.yaml content?

Comment: I read from https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/runtime and found mysqli already enabled. Hmm, maybe we missing something...

Comment: Is there a problem with this line dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=/usr/bin/php-cgi $PWD

Answer (score 0):

It looks like google app engine has support for mysqli by default. The problem was that connection to database needs to be configured in different way then when using regular hosts. It needs to go through socket

I used this settings in app.yaml file as env variables

```
env_variables:
MYSQL_DSN: mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/datahouse;dbname=mydatabase
MYSQL_USER: root
MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'mypassword'
```

I found this values in my database which is on cloud SQL. This fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by doing this:

> $instance_name = "/cloudsql/YOUR_PROJECT_ID_WITHOUT_DB_NAME";
>
> $mysqli = mysqli_connect(null, YOUR_DB_USER ,YOUR_DB_PASS, 'DB_NAME',null,$instance_name);

From the example above:

> MYSQL_DSN: mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/datahouse;dbname=mydatabase
>
> MYSQL_USER: root
>
> MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'mypassword'

Use only:

> $instance_name = "/cloudsql/datahouse";
>
> $mysqli = mysqli_connect(null, 'root' ,'mypassword', 'DB_NAME',null,$instance_name);

Hope it helps